# Relative Strength in Altcoins compared to Bitcoin

Tags: trading, portfolio-selection, strategy, cryptocurrency, active-investing

I trade stocks using relative strength analysis compared with S&P index. I was wondering if crypto traders do the same compared with Bitcoin price %change. These coins had a higher %gain than btc in the downtrend for a month.

https://ibb.co/1L3hNVd

Which of them would you select and why?

Is crypto exchange availability to trade in Altcoin important? I notice most of Altcoins that have large %gain do not trade in main exchanges until the major move have already happened.